# How is the code to the first keypad door in System Shock supposed to be found?

Tags: system-shock

In System Shock, on floor 1, the first locked door with the keypad right next to it requires a three digit code, which I know to be 451 due to searching online. However, my question is, how is the player supposed to know the code using any in-game means, that is, without searching for it online?

I've read all the emails and logs up to that point, collected every item so far, and none provide you with the actual code or any other means to bypass the keypad. I've searched for walkthroughs and let's plays, and in all of them they just input the code without actually explaining how they found it out. I've found some forum threads about it, but they always end up with someone just posting the code but no explanation as to how to obtain it. I've searched through the game manual, and it's not there. It's not on the box art. I'm seriously out of ideas. Am I missing something very obvious, or how were people able to get past the door back when the game first came out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is in the first log you receive.

Comment: I think it possible to miss that first log through some player mistake. I think I may have destroyed the briefcase without getting the log in it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to point it out, the answer to this is in the following Log :

> 2-4601-06.May.72
>   Sender: #2-4601

On page 3, there's an actual error/typo by the developers (or a translator) that explain why people might not notice the code. The sentence is written as "*First off, the **combo** to the healing suite is 451.*" instead of "*First off, the **code** to the healing suite is 451.*" The way the text is shown in this game isn't great when you try to find keys words that could give you an idea of what to do. That mixed with typing errors makes it harder on some players.

Comment: I can verify that the '451' code still works on the Unity demo (newly available on GoG), but the in-game written-down answer is gone. The briefcase in the entry way has a quiet, barely intelligible, scratchy, audio email with no codes, and no subtitles either. There is another, shorter, and similarly hard to understand audio only email in the medical bay. Nothing with pages or writing.

Comment: i think combo means combination not a typo

Comment: That’s not a typo or translation error. Combo is short for combination. A synonym for lock code that was somewhat more prevalent when the game was made, a more innocent era when so-called [combination locks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination_lock) were quite commonplace.